# Install docker 1.2 on Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ami, discourse

I'm trying to install discourse forum on the Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03. To install that forum I should use docker 1.2 or more but when I type "yum install docker" I getting version 1.1.2-1.0.amzn1 from amazon. So how can I download and install the last version from https://github.com/docker/docker?

Answer (score 4):

I found answer on my question here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7968

```
$ yum --enablerepo epel-testing install docker-io
```

Comment: I had some trouble with this at first. In order to get this to work you need to enable the epel repo on Amazon Linux: `sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`. Then set the `enabled` options to `1`.